# GPIO interrupts firing when not input provided

Tags: stm32, gpio, nucleo

I have a few GPIO pins configured as an input as well as a button.  The interrupt for the button works great (I need to add some debouncing).  But sometimes when the button is pushed, or if I just touch the header pins with my fingers, the other gio interrupts are firing.

The gio pins are configured with pull down resistors and set to fire on a rising edge.

For simplicity I have removed most of the gio pins I'm using and just shown one, but I have the following configured for input.

PA4, PA7,PA10, PB6, PB8, PB9

```
    // Enable GPIO Peripheral clock
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= BLINK_RCC_MASKx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER);

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    /*Configure GPIO pin : PC13 - Button input*/

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    //Init LED
    /*Configure GPIO pin : PA5 - LD2 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

}

void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void)
{

    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_7) != RESET)
    {
        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_7);


        //Do something
#ifdef DEBUG
        trace_printf("PA7 interrupt. Tick count: %u Counts\n", xTaskGetTickCount());
#endif
    }

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{

    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_10) != RESET)
    {
        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_10);

        //Do something
#ifdef DEBUG
        trace_printf("PA10 interrupt. Tick count: %u Counts\n", xTaskGetTickCount());
#endif

    }
    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_13) != RESET)
    {
        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);


        trace_printf("User Button Pushed. Tick count: %u Counts\n", xTaskGetTickCount());


    }
}
```

Comment: It could be electrical cross talk between the pins. You may need to add some capacitance and stronger pull down.

Comment: Somewhat related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447471/flaky-gpio-on-esp8266-how-do-i-solve-it